# Not able to create correct url in action class in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to react and using visual studio as IDE.
My action class is as follows:

```
import axios from 'axios';
const API_KEY = '28047d25df4cc300751f33977b21a9f0';
const ROOT_URL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid='+ API_KEY;
export const FETCH_WEATHER = 'FETCH_WEATHER'
export function fetchWeather(city) {
    const url = '${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},us';
    console.log("url",url);
    const request = axios(url);
    return {
        type: FETCH_WEATHER,
        payload: request 
    };
}
```

And if I am printing URL in console, result is as follows:

```
URL ${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},us
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Asd. Read this brief article on [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help improve your chance of having this answered. Specifically, clearly state what you expect to see versus what you actually see and provide a specific question

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

change this

```
const url = '${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},us';
```

to this

```
const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},us`;
```